# How do I display different values as different columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns `UserID, SiteID, SiteViews` and another with `UserID, First, Last`

And I need to display the data as `First + Last, Site1Views, Site2Views`

There are only 2 site IDs and I need to have the sum of the SiteViews per User.

Currently I have:

```
select s.UserFirstName + ' ' + s.UserLastName as 'Name', 
j1.SiteViews as 'Site1Name',
j2.SiteViews as 'Site2Name' 
from (Users s INNER JOIN Usage j on s.UserID = j.UserID)
```

I don't know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the primary/foreign key relationships between these tables?

Comment: UserID is the relationship being used. There is UsageID on the first table as the primary key as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to use PIVOT for this?  I can't test it, but this should get you going int he right direction?

```
select s.UserFirstName + ' ' + s.UserLastName as Name, 
       [Site1Name],
       [Site2Name]
FROM
       (SELECT s.UserFirstName + ' ' + s.UserLastName,
               SiteName,
               SiteVisits
        from Users s 
        INNER JOIN Usage j1 
          on s.UserID = j1.UserID
       )
PIVOT (SUM(SiteVisits) FOR SiteName IN ([Site1Name],[Site2Name])) as p
```

Comment: thanks! To be clear, the OtherUsageTable is the same as the first Usage table. i.e. I have UserID 1, SiteID 1, Views 200, UserID 1, SiteID 2, Views 300. Your statement did separate the 2 sites but the UserIDs aren't grouped and the Views are coming across in multiple records still.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Not sure if it will work, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

how I understood it

```
select s.UserFirstName + ' ' + s.UserLastName as Name 
,(Select COUNT(*) from SiteViews s1 where s.UserID = s1.UserID /*other condition*/) as SiteView1
,(Select COUNT(*) from SiteViews s2 where s.UserID = s2.UserID /*other condition*/) as SiteView2 
from Users s
```